# JavaScript Validation Registration Form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, registration

The validateForm function works. And the validateEmail function works as well but separately. How do I incorporate the data validation for the email in the validateForm function? In other words, how do I get the form to return false for when the fields are empty and requirements are not met?

```
  function validateForm() {

     if( document.myForm.userName.value == "" ) {
        alert( "Please provide your name!" );
        document.myForm.userName.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     if( document.myForm.email.value == "" ) {
        alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
        document.myForm.email.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     return( true );
  }

 function validateEmail() {
     var emailID = document.myForm.email.value;
     atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
     dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");

     if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) {
        alert("Please enter correct email ID")
        document.myForm.email.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     return( true );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to merge your code into one function

```
  function validateForm() {

    var emailID = document.myForm.email.value;
    atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
    dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");

     if( document.myForm.userName.value == "" ) {
        alert( "Please provide your name!" );
        document.myForm.userName.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     if( document.myForm.email.value == "" ) {
        alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
        document.myForm.email.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) {
        alert("Please enter correct email ID")
        document.myForm.email.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     return true;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

just called validateEmail inside validateForm like this :

```
function validateForm() {

 if( document.myForm.userName.value == "" ) {
    alert( "Please provide your name!" );
    document.myForm.userName.focus() ;
    return false;
 }
 if( document.myForm.email.value == "" ) {
    alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
    document.myForm.email.focus() ;
    return false;
 }
 return validateEmail();
}

function validateEmail() {
 var emailID = document.myForm.email.value;
 atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
 dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");

 if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) {
    alert("Please enter correct email ID")
    document.myForm.email.focus() ;
    return false;
 }
 return( true );
}
```

or u can u merge those function into like answer from @Addis